# Using moto with pandas read_parquet and to_parquet functions

Tags: python, pandas, mocking, pytest, moto

I am trying to write a unit test for a function which uses `pd.read_parquet()` function and I am struggling to make it work. I have the code below

```
from moto import mock_aws
import pandas as pd
import pytest
import datetime as dt
import boto3
from my_module import foo

@pytest.fixture
def mock_df():
    cols = [
        "timestamp",
        "value"
    ]
    values = [
        [dt.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 0), 2.57],
        [dt.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 1), 1.41],
        [dt.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 2), 2.06],
    ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=cols)
    return df


@mock_aws
def test_download(mock_df):
    bucket_name = "test-input-bucket"
    s3 = boto3.resource("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
    key1 = "s3://test-input-bucket/path/to/data.parquet"
    mock_df.to_parquet(key1) # code fails already here
    foo() # uses pd.read_parquet()
```

But I am getting this error

```
OSError: When initiating multiple part upload for key 'path/to/data.parquet'
in bucket 'test-input-bucket': AWS Error INVALID_ACCESS_KEY_ID during 
CreateMultipartUpload operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

I am getting the same error whether I use `to_parquet` or try to use `read_parquet`. Everything works fine, if I use something diffrent for the upload and download, like

```
s3_bucket.put_object(Key=key1, Body=mock_df.to_parquet())
```

However I am not interested in replacing the pandas functions as it is not possible in my situation and need to find a way to mock S3 while using them. Is there a way to make `moto` work with these functions?

EDIT:
I am using these versions

```
boto3                                    1.28.64
botocore                                 1.31.64
moto                                     5.0.3
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue, and it popped out when I had to update from mock_s3 to mock_aws. beforehand it worked just fine.

Comment: I found this 
https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/39880
it seems we have to pin moto?

Comment: I pinned moto to <5 to revert back to mock_s3 but things are still breaking, so in my case I am not sure anymore is due to moto.

Comment: ok if you switch - if you can - to `engine='fastparquet'` this should pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed the issue on my end. I am not 100% applies to every single case.

On our end we narrowed the issue indeed to using `to_parquet` or `read_parquet` in tests.
Using `fastparquet` as the engine (`engine='fastparquet'`) seemed to provide a solution, but for us it wasn't always possible.

For some reason, `pyarrow` wants credentials, whereas other packages don't care. Adding credentials and forcing them at the creation of the connection did the trick for us.
So something like

```py
@pytest.fixture
def aws_credentials():
    """Mocked AWS Credentials for moto."""
    os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"] = "testing"


@mock_aws
def test_file(aws_credentials, mock_df):
    with mock_aws(aws_credentials):
        conn = boto3.client("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
        yield conn
    conn.create_bucket(Bucket="testbucket")
```

allowed us to have access to the bucket.
Let me know if it works on your end as well.